# Power BI DAX to SUMX cross rows, issue : summing up 0 as 1

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am creating multiple measures.

What I am trying to get Qty 2 to sum Qty 1.
Qty 1 is already a measure created from another measure.
To get Qty 2 I used DAX as below.

```
Qty2 = 
  CALCULATE(
    SUMX( Table, [Qty1] ),
     REMOVEFILTERS( Table[Store], Table[Size] )
  )
```

Expected result :

| Product ID | SIZE | STORE | Qty 1 | Qty 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAAAA | 100 | A | 1 | 4 |
| AAAAA | 100 | B | 0 | 4 |
| AAAAA | 200 | A | 3 | 4 |

Current result : The qty 1 is adding up 1 if there is any 0 on qty 1.

| Product ID | SIZE | STORE | Qty 1 | Qty 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAAAA | 100 | A | 1 | 5 |
| AAAAA | 100 | B | 0 | 5 |
| AAAAA | 200 | A | 3 | 5 |

Qty 1 is also measure, so cannot use SUM.
How can I fix this issue?

[image: Example as screenshot]

Expected result :

| Product ID | SIZE | STORE | Qty 1 | Qty 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAAAA | 100 | A | 1 | 4 |
| AAAAA | 100 | B | 0 | 4 |
| AAAAA | 200 | A | 3 | 4 |

Comment: Update your question with the dax for `[Qty1]`, I suspect the `REMOVEFILTERS` is influencing the calculation of `[Qty1]`. For example, create a new measure with `Qty2 Test =  CALCULATE( [Qty1] , REMOVEFILTERS( Table[Store], Table[Size] )  )` and I think you won't get `0` for when size is 190.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a shot in the dark (without knowing what `[Qty1]` dax is). Try:

```
Qty2 v2 =
  SUMX(
    CALCULATETABLE( Table, ALLEXCEPT(Table, Table[Product ID]) ),
    [Qty1]
  )
```

---

Version 3 hopefully should do it this time.

```
Qty2 v3 =
  var productIds = VALUES('Table'[Product ID])
  var tbl = ADDCOLUMNS(
    FILTER( ALL('Table'), 'Table'[Product ID] in productIds ),
    "Qty1", [Qty1]
  )

  RETURN SUMX( tbl, [Qty1] )
```

If that doesn't work then create a Calculated Table with:

```
_debug Qty1 = ADDCOLUMNS( 'Table', "Qty1", [Qty1] )
```

And confirm Qty1 is returning the correct expected values.

Comment: Result is same..
The Qty1 Dax is using IF 
Qty 1 = IF ([WH_QTY] - [A_QTY] >=0, [A_QTY],[WH_QTY])
WH_QTY,A_QTY is also measure.

Comment: Update your question then with what the dax is for `Qty1`. Even better, create a simple pbix with dummy data that reproduces the issue, and then share it via a public link.

Comment: Added v3 to the answer above. Please confirm that `Product ID`, `SIZE`, and `STORE` columns are in the same table.